# Combining several data frames in hierarchical manner

Tags: r, merge

I have three tables in R. The first table lists out the number of people under the highest level term. The second table lists the number of people within each severity level of the highest level term. The third table lists the number of people within each subcategory of the highest level term based on their severity level. Here are examples of the tables

Table 1

```
HighestOrderTerm     Total
           Term1         4
           Term2         6
           Term3         5
```

Table 2

```
HighestOrderTerm       SeverityLevel       Total
           Term1          Level 1           2
           Term1          Level 3           2
           Term2          Level 2           4
           Term2          Level 3           2
           Term3          Level 3           4
           Term3          Level 5           1
```

Table 3

```
HighestOrderTerm       SecondOrderTerm       SeverityLevel       Total
           Term1             Category1             Level 1           2
           Term1             Category2             Level 3           2
           Term2             Category3             Level 2           1                  
           Term2             Category4             Level 2           3
           Term2             Category5             Level 2           1
           Term2             Category6             Level 3           2
           Term3             Category7             Level 3           1
           Term3             Category8             Level 3           3
           Term3             Category9             Level 5           1
```

I would like the final table to look like the following:

```
    HighestOrderTerm
       SecondOrderTerm
          SeverityLevel           Total

    Term1                            4
          Level1                     2
          Level3                     2

      Category1                      2
          Level1                     2
          Level2                     2

    Term2                            6
          Level2                     4
          Level3                     2

       Category3                     1
          Level2                     1
       Category4                     3
          Level2                     3
       Category5                     1
          Level2                     1
       Category6                     2
          Level3                     2


    Term3                            5
          Level2                     4
          Level3                     1

       Category7                     1
          Level3                     1
       Category8                     3
          Level3                     3
       Category9                     1
          Level5                     1
```

Comment: R data structures are not directly designed for reporting with nested headers, hierarchical columns, skipped lines. Consider developing a text file from raw data, xml/json, or even html incorporated in R markdown.

Comment: To echo @Parfait's comment, you can look into packages like `kableExtra`, `huxtable`, and others to generate the HTML documents to represent such a table.

Comment: @Brian and Parfait, thanks for the heads up. I have previously used kableExtra, I'll look in to that.